Problem removing READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission to use Photo Picker in android app
On Google's recommendation, I removed READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission from my app for using PhotoPicker and its now working when the app remains installed. The app saves it to the gallery and I can recover the photo.
However, if I uninstall the app and install it again, I can no longer read this saved photo because I don't have permission.
How should I proceed in these cases?
I wasn't able to make much progress on a solution.

In Android, starting from Android 13 (API level 33), Google introduced the Photo Picker API as a privacy-friendly way to access images and videos without needing to request the READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission. However, when you uninstall and reinstall your app, you lose access to the files created in the previous installation, especially since you no longer have broad file access due to the removed permission.
I think you should have Save the image in a shared storage location, Instead of saving the photo to your app's internal storage, you should save it to a shared directory like the Pictures or DCIM folder in external storage. This way, the image will persist even if the app is uninstalled, and since the Photo Picker has access to shared storage, you can pick the image after reinstallation without needing any additional permissions.
you can do like this example for java :
public void saveImageToPictures(Bitmap bitmap, String fileName) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName + ".jpg");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    try (OutputStream outputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri)) {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

if you are doing in kotlin then like this :
fun saveImageToPictures(bitmap: Bitmap, fileName: String) {
    val values = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "$fileName.jpg")
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    }

    val resolver = contentResolver
    val uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

    uri?.let {
        try {
            resolver.openOutputStream(it)?.use { outputStream ->
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

I think this is the best option, Save the images in a shared location like the Pictures folder. This allows the images to persist even if the app is uninstalled, and you can easily retrieve them with the Photo Picker.
